# Gradle Build export error in Android ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-studio

I want to export my project by generating gradle build file for using it in Android Studio but when I try to export and select my project on selection window I'm not able to proceed by the error saying  "Different modules have been detected on different drives.This prevents finding a common root to all modules."It works fine in Android ADT 22.0.1 but not working in 22.0.4

Whats the problem here.Please tell anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a bug which will be fixed in next ADT release : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57924